# Is it okay that I turned on my new fridge immediately after delivery?

Tags: refrigerator

I turned on my new fridge/freezer immediately after delivery without thinking about it. Just realised, now 3 hours later, and went downstairs. It felt cold but I could hear "liquidy" noises. Have I screwed it? I was under the impression that it would be transported "upright" because that's what it says on the box.

Any advice/comments? I have just turned it off out of paranoia.

Comment: When the store's installers brought my fridge, they plugged it in immediately after they installed it so they could get me to sign off that it worked (i.e., it was cold) before they left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal for fridges to make all sorts of sounds. Some of it will be materials contracting, the compressor running, etc.  If you have a water dispenser or ice maker, you will occasionally hear water flowing.

You are supposed to let a fridge sit a bit after delivery, but most people will just plug them in.

I doubt you have damaged your fridge.  Plug it back in, let it cool down for 24hours, and assuming it keeps working, you're in the clear.

Comment: Given the lack of responses, and the general hysteria on forums, I think this is going to be right. It hasn't blown up or anything yet! Thanks.